# Sensible way to encode user defined sort-order in back end database?

Tags: firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a series of "rows" in a collection which are persisted to a nosql database (in this case Firestore).  Each one of my rows has a sort order which is established when the user adds, inserts, copies or moves rows with the collection.  The  insertion point into which a user may insert new records is arbitrary.  The sort order is persisted to the backend, and can be retrieved ordered by the sort order field.  There may be a large number of rows in the collection, on the order 50K.

The question what is the sort order encoding format that would permit repeated insertion of new records between existing records, without having to occasionally rewrite the sort index of the entire collection to provide "space" in the sort order between adjacent records.

I'm guessing there may some standard way to achieve this, but not sure what it is.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.collectionsjs.com/sorted-array Can't vouch for it's performance though.

Comment: Sounds to me like the solution may not be suited to NoSQL too. Persisting 50k rows - of what size each...

Comment: https://dev.to/miku86/javascript-data-structures-doubly-linked-list-intro-and-setup-275b

Comment: Row data is small maybe 1k per row

Comment: Linked list doesn’t much help as inefficient to retrieve from the backend I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the alphabet is "abc". Then:

b, c, cb...

is a lexicographically sorted list that allows you to insert items anywhere:

ab, b, bb, c, cab, cb, cbb...

And the result is still a list that allows you to insert items anywhere:

aab, ab, ac, b, bab, bb, bc, c, caab, cab, cac, cb, cbab, cbb, cbbb...

*The trick is to avoid having "a" as the last character of an item, so that you can always put items behind others.*

Do this with 64 ASCII characters instead of 3.

I've been thinking about this for quite a few months. This is my progress so far in implementing it. It still has some flaws and it's a little bit of a mess, but I guess I'll clean it and upload it at npm when I find more time.

```js
// Originally written in TypeScript, then removed the types for SO.
const alphabet = 'abc';

function getHigherAsciiChar(char) {
    const index = alphabet.indexOf(char);
    if (index === alphabet.length - 1) {
        return ''; // sorry, there's no higher character
    }
    const nextIndex = Math.ceil((index + alphabet.length - 1) / 2);
    return alphabet.charAt(nextIndex);
}

function getCharBetween(minChar, maxChar) {
    if (minChar > maxChar) {
        throw new Error('minChar > maxChar, ' + minChar + ' > ' + maxChar);
    }
    const minIndex = alphabet.indexOf(minChar);
    const maxIndex = alphabet.indexOf(maxChar);
    const nextIndex = Math.floor((minIndex + maxIndex) / 2);
    if (nextIndex === minIndex) {
        return ''; // there is no character between these two
    }
    return alphabet.charAt(nextIndex);
}

function getPaddedString(finalLength, string) {
    let result = string;
    while (result.length < finalLength) {
        result += alphabet.charAt(0);
    }
    return result;
}

function getOrderString(bounds) {
    const console = { log: () => {} }; //  uncomment this to log debug stuff
    if (!bounds.previous && !bounds.next) {
        return getHigherAsciiChar(alphabet[0]);
    }
    const previousString = bounds.previous || '';
    if (!bounds.next) {
        const firstPreviousChars = previousString.substr(0, previousString.length - 1);
        const lastPreviousChar = previousString.charAt(previousString.length - 1);
        return firstPreviousChars + (
            getHigherAsciiChar(lastPreviousChar) || (
                lastPreviousChar + getHigherAsciiChar(alphabet.charAt(0))
            )
        );
    }
    const nextString = bounds.next;
    console.log(`Searching between '${previousString}' and '${nextString}'...`);
    const bigStringLength = Math.max(previousString.length, nextString.length);
    const previous = getPaddedString(bigStringLength, previousString);
    const next = getPaddedString(bigStringLength, nextString);
    console.log(previous, next);
    let result = '';
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < bigStringLength; i++) {
        const previousChar = previous.charAt(i);
        const nextChar = next.charAt(i);
        // keep adding common characters
        if (previousChar === nextChar) {
            result += previousChar;
            console.log(result, 'common character');
            continue;
        }
        // when different characters are reached, try to add a character between these two
        const charBetween = getCharBetween(previousChar, nextChar);
        if (charBetween) {
            result += charBetween;
            console.log(result, 'character in-between. RETURNING');
            // and you're done
            return result;
        }
        // if there was no character between these two (their distance was exactly 1),
        // repeat the low character, forget about the upper bound and just try to get bigger than lower bound
        result += previousChar;
        console.log(result, 'the lower character so we can forget about high bound');
        i++;
        break;
    }
    for (; previousString >= result; i++) {
        const previousChar = previous.charAt(i);
        const higherChar = getHigherAsciiChar(previousChar);
        if (higherChar) {
            // you found a digit that makes your result greater than the lower bound. You're done.
            result += higherChar;
            console.log(result, 'a higher character. RETURING');
            return result;
        }
        // the digits are still very close, can't find a digit in-between (yet)
        result += previousChar;
        console.log(result, 'moving on to next digit');
    }
    // so you end up depleting all the character slots from the lower bound. Meh, just add any character.
    result += getHigherAsciiChar(alphabet.charAt(0));
    console.log(result, 'meh, just add any character. RETURNING');
    return result;
}

function interleaveTest(order) {
    const newOrder = [];
    newOrder.push(getOrderString({ next: order[0] }));
    for (let i = 0; i < order.length - 1; i++) {
        newOrder.push(order[i]);
        newOrder.push(getOrderString({ previous: order[i], next: order[i + 1] }));
    }
    newOrder.push(order[order.length - 1]);
    newOrder.push(getOrderString({ previous: order[order.length - 1] }));
    return newOrder;
}

let order = ['c'];
console.log('\n' + order.join(', ') + '\n');
order = interleaveTest(order);
console.log('\n' + order.join(', ') + '\n');
order = interleaveTest(order);
console.log('\n' + order.join(', ') + '\n');
order = interleaveTest(order);
console.log('\n' + order.join(', ') + '\n');

let atEnd = ['b'];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    atEnd.push(getOrderString({ previous: atEnd[atEnd.length - 1] }));
}
console.log('\nat end: ' + atEnd.join(', ') + '\n');
```

Comment: Yes, although this gets complicated, for example, if you have a set [ b, c, cb], and then your user wants to insert a row before b, which has to be a, and then they want to insert another row before a, you're forced to change at least two records (make the new first record "a", and the second record "aa" -and then the user wants insert a record between "a" and "aa" etc etc.  I wish somebody would have written this already.

Comment: @user1023110 If you want to insert something before `b`, you don't insert `a`, you insert `ab`. Then there is still room at both sides.

Comment: ah right, but lets say you then want to sequentially insert 3 more records at the top:  so the first one would be aa and then a and then ?

Comment: @user1023110 the "at the top" is trivial, you just increment (in ASCII) the last character, and if you run out of characters, instead of incrementing, you append the 2nd character of your alphabet. I've done this a lot with realtime database, but I've always updated all the "order" values any time the user adds elements somewhere. In RTDB it's not disastrous (it's just a big multi-path update), but with Firestore it would be, because it would charge you for N document writes.

Comment: (This was made as an upgrade from calling `.push()` N times when saving big lists, so now instead of N new unique incrementing values, we get N standard incrementing values, that are also of smaller size. We append the 2nd character instead of the 1st, so that in the future we can create values in between, but we haven't needed that yet.)

Comment: I'll try to make and post some working code for this in the following days.

Comment: Regarding your "at the top" case, assuming the alphabet is "abc", it goes like `b, c, cb, cc, ccb, ccc...`.

Comment: Your comment about avoiding having to write the sort index in the whole collection is exactly the point.   I am wondering about an algorithm where the sort key is either very unlikely to have to be rewritten entirely and where changing the sort requires only rewriting one document

Comment: I’m not sure you have understood my question on your example tho.   Writing new records at the front of the repeatedly without having to rewrite all records seems challenging. In your example if you have b, c, cb, you will run into problems if you insert 3 records at the top of the collection sequentially.   If you under ab at the front, the. The next insertion has to be “a” and the. You are forced to write multiple records not just the record inserted

Comment: @user1023110 Writing at the front of `b` gives you `ab, b`, then `aab, ab, b`.

Comment: This code you provided works great, except for I"m not sure what the arguments to the getOrderString function should be in the case where you are adding a key to the end of the collection.  If you don't provide an after key or set it '', the method adds a character on every row append which gets extremely long very quickly.  What are right bounds params for adding to the end of the collection?

Comment: @user1023110 Yeah, I noticed that flaw. I updated the code to better handle that case.

Comment: @user1023110 Also notice how `getHigherAsciiChar` skips characters in order to make plenty of space for intermediate values that won't need to be longer. If you find that most of your cases are "appends", you might want to change `getHigherAsciiChar` to just increment the character (no skipping).

Comment: Now it goes like `1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 95, 97, 98, 99...`, so that you can add `2` or `93` later. If you wanted to favor appends, it would go like`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 91, 92...`, but an intermediate value would require extra characters (`101` or `901`).

Comment: I think the typical use case will be appends in my application.  They will tend to add to the end of the list except sometimes somebody will want to insert somethiing or copy and paste.

Comment: @user1023110 Then I think replacing `const nextIndex = Math.ceil((index + alphabet.length - 1) / 2);` with `const nextIndex = index + 1;` (in `getHigherAsciiChar`) would do the job well.